# Data inserting in mysql data base not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am inserting data in mysql data base using following code

```
<?php

   $con = mysql_connect("surveyipad.db.6420177.hostedresource.com","test","test");
  if (!$con)
   {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

  mysql_select_db("surveyipad", $con);

  $response_id=$_POST['response_id'];

  $participant_id=$_POST['participant_id']

  $question_id=$_POST['question_id'];

 $answer_text=$_POST['answer_text'];

 echo($response_id);

   $query=("INSERT INTO survey_question_responses 

  (response_id,participant_id,question_id,answer_option)
   VALUES ('$response_id', '$participant_id','$question_id','$answer_option')");

   mysql_query($query,$con);
  printf("Records inserted: %d\n", mysql_affected_rows());
  echo($response_id)
  ?>
```

My table in mysql is like

response_id,participant_id,question_id,answer_option_answer_text

Comment: If something's not working, **check for errors**. For example using `echo mysql_error()`.

Comment: yes it is giving error like Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/content/i/h/u/ihus235/html/cs/emrapp/SyncSurveyTest.php on line 16

Comment: @Vprimachenko i have given the error in comment please check this

Comment: @UmerSumra missing semicolon after `$_POST['participant_id']` also look into `PDO`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**response_id,participant_id,question_id,answer_option_answer_text** vs

**(response_id,participant_id,question_id,answer_option)**

and your line "  $participant_id=$_POST['participant_id']
" is missing its **semicolon (;)**

also please use

```
if( !mysql_query( $query, $con ) ) { 
echo("Failure: " . mysql_error()  ); 
}
```

to insert data.

Comment: thanks it worked but respone id is integer format i think it is storing 0 values how to fix this issue all other workign fine

Comment: dont add the '' around '$response_id' within your  VALUES ('$response_id'[...] line. Then it is parsed as an integer in mysql. That does not help when the variable itself is empty. You would neet to verify that before inserting data (with if(!isset($variable)) )